# Chaining async functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await, ecmascript-2017

```
let val = 0;

async function first() {
    console.log('1a', val);
    second();
    console.log('1b', val);
}

async function second() {
    console.log('2a', val);
    third();
    console.log('2b', val);
}

async function third() {
    console.log('3a', val);
    val = await new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            resolve(3);
        }, 1000);
    });
    console.log('3b', val);
}

console.log('0a', val);
first();
console.log('0b', val);
```

I am expecting:

```
0a 0
1a 0
2a 0
3a 0
3b 3
2b 3
1b 3
0b 3
```

But I am receiving:

```
0a 0
1a 0
2a 0
3a 0
2b 0
1b 0
0b 0
3b 3
```

I'm guessing there is a fundamental thing about async which I am unaware of?

Comment: Only `third` is `await`ing the result of a promise, all your other functions execute synchronously. Unless you `await` `first` and `second`, they're going to return immediately.

Comment: Well, I don't know much about `await` and `async` but surely the timeout part is basically allowing the rest of the code to finish while the `await` waits for the timeout to finish? (or more specifically for the `Promise` to finish)

Comment: Wait, what version of nodejs even supports this syntax? I've tried with v6.8.1 and it throws a syntax error.

Comment: @freakish 7 with --harmony flag http://node.green/#async-functions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to use

```
async function first() {
    console.log('1a', val);
    await second();
//  ^^^^^
    console.log('1b', val);
}

async function second() {
    console.log('2a', val);
    await third();
//  ^^^^^
    console.log('2b', val);
}
```

to chain the `b` logs after the asynchronous execution of the called functions.

And it's the same for

```
console.log('0a', val);
first();
console.log('0b', val);
```

only that you cannot use `await` here since you are not inside an `aync function`. Making a function `async` doesn't mean that it magically blocks on everything asynchronous inside it, on the contrary - its result becomes a promise that is *always* asynchronous, and you can use the `await` keyword. So to make `0b` wait, you can use either

```
console.log('0a', val);
first().then(function() {
    console.log('0b', val);
}, function(err) {
    console.error(err);
});
```

or

```
(async function() {
    try {
        console.log('0a', val);
        first();
        console.log('0b', val);
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}());
```

Answer (score 4):

You will have to `await` all async function calls:

```
async function first() {
    console.log('1a', val);
    await second();
    console.log('1b', val);
}

async function second() {
    console.log('2a', val);
    await third();
    console.log('2b', val);
}
```

Comment: The fundamental thing I forgot was that the async returns a promise.